# SOA Web Services Maturity Models

Tags: web-services, soa, maturity

I am quite familiar with development of a SOA Web Service with several languages, but this time I need to develop one in maturity model 3. I have done a long search thorugh Google but I have found this only (summerized):

It is the 3rd step of 5, which either focuses to create in-organization improvements or providing information to external organizations.

Is that really it? My service already targets communication and information sharing with external parties, so is is maturity standard 3b compatible now? If anyone knows anything about SOA maturity levels, it would be veeery helpdul.

Thanks

Comment: It is not apparent  which SOA maturity model you are referring to OMG? the Open group's etc.  - the real question though is why bother?

Comment: OMG = object management group (and not Oh My Glub :-P) see: http://www.omg.org/soa/Uploaded%20Docs/SOA/SOA_Maturity.pdf